# UITableViewでチェックリストを作成する

Tags: swift, xcode

UITableViewでチェックリストを作ってみたのですが、現在Cellを押すとチェックリストのUIImageが変更されます。Cellを押すと別のUITableViewに移動でき、UIImageを押下時にのみ画像が変更されるようにするにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

```
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

    var checkListItem: [String : Bool] = [
        "アイテム1" : false,
        "アイテム2" : false,
    ]

    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // UITableView の作成
        tableView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: statusBarHeight,
            width: self.view.frame.width,
            height: self.view.frame.height - statusBarHeight
        )
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var keys = [String](checkListItem.keys)

        keys.sort()

        let cellText = keys[indexPath.row]

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellText

        if self.checkListItem[cellText]! {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "checked")
        } else {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked")
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {

            let cellText = cell.textLabel?.text

            if cell.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "checked") {

                self.checkListItem.updateValue(false, forKey: cellText!)
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked")
            } else {

                self.checkListItem.updateValue(true, forKey: cellText!)
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "checked")
            }

            cell.isSelected = false
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 56
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.checkListItem.count
    }
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/63532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

二種類の解決法があると思います。ひとつは、カスタムのセル（`UITableViewCell`のサブクラス）を作り、イメージを`UIButton`としてセルに貼り付け、タップしたら自身の`image`を変更するアクションをつけることです。すこし大きなプログラムになります。
もうひとつは、方針を若干変更して、Appleの「[ヒューマンインターフェイスガイドライン](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html)」に従ったものにすることです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

スクリーンショットのように、DetailButton（`UITableViewCellAccessoryType.detailButton`）をセルに表示します。
`UITableViewDelegate`メソッドを、コードに追加します。画面遷移の種類は、モーダル表示、遷移先のView Controllerを`ModalViewController`とします。

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let controller = ModalViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

セルをタップしたら、イメージが変更することは変わりませんが、Detailボタンをタップすると、モーダルに遷移するようになります。方針と異なりますが、できることは同じです。